# Is there anything that could be done that crawlers see ajax (dynamic) content on the wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, web-crawler, seo

I am not sure if this is the correct forum to ask the question, but I am facing a "big trouble" on my website regarding the SEO.

My website runs on Wordpress and is built through elementor builder, but has a lot of content that is dynamic and delivered to the site by Ajax.

I was wondering if there is anything I can do so the content is visible to crawlers ?

Comment: [webmasters.se]?

Comment: Too broad for that site

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.